# Needing to run fsck -fy "often" should I send to repair?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility

Every month I usually give a go to Onyx so I repair all permissions and such. Every time I do that, I get that I need to repair the Disk and I end up having to boot with the single user (in which I see a hint of an error but goes quickly) and then use the `fsck -fy` command. After a couple of runs it gets solved and everything seems ok.

However, I'm a bit afraid that the disk goes off some day. Any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

First wipe the drive entirely. Repartition and then give it one more chance. Unless you want to blame a corrupt OS or really bad programs, this is likely a failing drive and not bad data or bad OS.